# Convert Array to Map Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I'm trying to covert the following array to a Map:

```
const arr = [
  { key: 'user1', value: { num: 0, letter: 'a' } },
  { key: 'user2', value: { num: 0, letter: 'b' } },
  { key: 'user3', value: { num: 0, letter: 'c' } },
];
```

What I have so far:

```
const arr = [
  { key: 'user1', value: { num: 0, letter: 'a' } },
  { key: 'user2', value: { num: 0, letter: 'b' } },
  { key: 'user3', value: { num: 0, letter: 'c' } },
];
const b = arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.value]);
const map = new Map<string, { num: number; letter: string }>(b);

console.log(map.get('user1'));
```

Do you know if this is something achievable?

*PS: You can find Typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBj3BvGAawFMBPALhgHIBXCYhARioBoYA3OAGxuMoLA0AtpQAMbLsShQGlKnCowAvspbZcOAiQrU6DAEysO3XvxiCRMcTEnTZ1AEaKVStRs1EycvQgDMRzh4+GAFhMQkpGQQ5YGdVdRwAXQBuBJhQSFgHVHgkADohOAAHAAoQBwArVAA+DHKKvO02erzA3kSASlSNDOgYQqKcsGIAdxgAWWKAHmgEAEswAHM2UMsLBwZkm0j7WYXF5WqShy71dV6QSTyuEEWSgbzFqRLaeiYqDq6gA) and the error that I'm getting*

Comment: If you do it all in one line TypeScript infers the correct type [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wvavrm) `const map = new Map(arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.value]));`

Comment: `const map = new Map(arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.value]));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`obj.key` is a `string`, and `obj.value` is a `{num: number, letter: string}`, so if you make an array of them (`[obj.key, obj.value]`), then you get an `Array<string | {num: number, letter: string}>`.

You need to tell TypeScript that you're creating a specific [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), as expected by the Map constructor, not a generic array. There are a few ways of doing this:

```
// The simplest: Tell TypeScript "I mean exactly what I said."
// (This makes it readonly, which isn't always desirable.)
const b = arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.value] as const);

// Or be explicit in a return type. You can do this at a few levels.
const b = arr.map<[string, { num: number, letter: string}]>(obj => [obj.key, obj.value]);
const b = arr.map((obj): [string, { num: number, letter: string}] => [obj.key, obj.value]);

// Or, as explained in the comments, do it in one line, and TypeScript
// can infer tuple vs. array itself.
const map = new Map(arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.value]));
```